# PHP: Facebook deixa eu postar no meu feed mas os outros usuários não conseguem no deles

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou criando um sistema de postagens no facebook. Criei um aplicativo e coloquei como público. Através do aplicativo peço as seguintes permissões:

- publish_actions
- manage_pages
- publish_pages
- pages_show_list
- public_profile
- email
- user_managed_groups
- user_posts
- user_likes

No sistema eu programo para postar no meu feed. No horário programado ele posta corretamente. O problema ocorre com outros usuários.

Os outros usuários fazem o mesmo processo, mas não publica e da o erro:

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this
>   action.

Utilizo o Token do Usuário para efetuar a postagem, mas só o meu, que sou dono do aplicativo funciona. Quando clicam no botão para logar com o facebook, me parece que as permissões que pede para os usuários é menos que pede pra mim, não sei o motivo, mas é o que parece.

A função que uso é mais ou menos:

> $post = $this->request('post', '/'.$id_page.'/feed', $params, $token);

```
$id_page = ID do Perfil
$params = Array que contem `message` com a mensagem do post
$token = token do usuário gerado
```

Estou usando o `SDK v.2.8`

Comment: Creio que falta autorizar o aplicativo, verifica se ele esta em modo de desenvolvimento, já tive um problema parecido, só eu consegui executar o login, quando eu testava funcionava, quando outros testavam não, por que tinha faltado eu permitir para todos e não só para testers

Comment: @MarceloBoni Eu já liberei para o público, mas mesmo assim não funciona para eles. Estava vendo o menu "Revisão" e acho que preciso pedir para o facebook liberar as permissões que preciso. Será isso ?